# Imprime el valor pero retorna undefined

Tags: javascript

Estoy trabajando en esta función toCamelCase que recibe como parametro un string, y lo que se intenta hacer es que cuando entra en el if, retorne el caracter en mayuscula del proximo elemento del array, pero retorna undefined, pero cuando dentro de la funcion imprimo su valor con un console.log, sí imprime el valor correspondiente.

```js
function toCamelCase(str){
    str.split('').forEach((element, index) => {
        if (element === '-' || element === '_')
            return (str.split('')[index+1].toUpperCase())
    });
}

console.log(toCamelCase('hola-que-tal'))
```

En este caso retorna undefined.
Ahora en el siguiente caso, sí imprime la letra en mayúscula:

```js
function toCamelCase(str){
    str.split('').forEach((element, index) => {
        if (element === '-' || element === '_')
            console.log((str.split('')[index+1].toUpperCase()))
    });
}

toCamelCase('hola-que-tal')
```

Lo único que hice fué cambiar el return que está dentro del if, por un console.log, mi pregunta es, por que en el console.log si imprime el valor, pero cuando lo retorno, me devuelve undefined?

Comment: @HeynerMartinez cuando hago 'hola-que-tal'.split(''), lo que retorna es un array con los caracteres del string. El output en este caso sería ['h', 'o', 'l', 'a', '-', 'q', 'u', 'e', '-', 't', 'a', 'l'], lo puedes probar

Comment: ya te lo puse como respuesta verifica si es así como lo deseabas

Answer (score 1):

Haces el split por cada carácter del string y luego, en el foreach, vueeelves y haces el split por cada carácter que recorres. Es raro! Posiblemente, además, te vas a salir del array y no he logrado replicar el funcionamiento del primer script; ambos dicen undefined

De acuerdo a la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), forEach siempre retorna `undefined` y va a ejecutar el callback que le indiques por cada elemento. Así pues, el camino no es retornar directo (porque va a decolver el undefined) y al sacar cosas por la consola estándar, te ahorras algunas cosas y evitas el return.

Lo que funcionaría, por ejemplo, es hacer las cosas una sola vez. Un ejemplo simple:

```js
function toCamelCase(str){
  
  let pepito = '';
  
  str.split('').forEach((element) => {
    if (element !== '-' && element !== '_')
      pepito += element.toUpperCase();
    
  });
  
  return pepito;
}

console.log('Salida:' + toCamelCase('hola-que-tal'))
```

Comment: Lo que pasa es que en el split del forEach lo que quiero es retornar el siguiente elemento en mayuscula, no el mismo elemento, se me ocurrió hacerlo así para tener el proximo elemento del elemento actual, quizás sí sea raro, pero es lo que se me ocurrió, estoy abierto a nuevas formas de hacerlo

Comment: @JesusDiaz en el fondo, lo que estás intentando hacer con ese código es que, si el carácter ES guión o underscore, traiga el siguiente y corres el riesgo de salirte del array. Si agarras el IF y lo inviertes, traes a tu string solución lo que NO es guión ni underscore, sin temor de salirte del array ni validaciones adicionales. Yo ahí estoy haciendo lo mismo sin saltar posiciones y usando UN foreach; la complejidad del algoritmo es menor y tarda menos

Comment: entiendo, tienes razón, pero mi pregunta es por qué cuando hago un console.log donde pongo el return dentro del foreach, me imprime el valor, pero cuando lo retorno, me retorna undefined, sí me explico? o sea, me interesa saber ese detalle. En ese ejemplo de 'hola-que-tal' no hay posibilidad de salirse del array porque no hay guión en la última posición, pero nuevamente, me interesa saber es por qué si imprimo dentro del foreach me da el valor, pero si lo retorno me da undefined

Comment: Respuesta actualizada

Comment: Muchisimas gracias

Answer (score -1):

Aqui esta como tu lo deseas, prueba a ver si esta correcto con lo que necesitas

```js
        function toCamelCase(str){
            str.split('').forEach((element, index) => {
                if (element === '-' || element === '_')
                {
               
               let valor=str.split('')[index+1].toUpperCase();
             str=str.replace(str.substr(index+1,1),valor);
                         }
            });
            console.log(str);
        }

        toCamelCase('hola-que-tal')
```

Comment: Por favor, añáde siempre una breve explicación de por qué tu código resuelve la pregunta, cómo se usa, etc. De otra forma, puede caer como respuesta de baja calidad